# Convert String to Object Key Name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm sending different objects to a component outside, and component data varies depending on objects. I'm getting the names with the Object.key function because the keywords I send have different key. Then I want to sort by the key. For this I need to define the name I received with Object.key function. How can I do it?

```
 upSortTable(items, val) {
  //items = Object,
  //val = index
  let Keys = Object.keys(items[0]); // ["item_id","item_title"]
  let keyname = Keys[val]; //item_id String value
  //want to use in sort function as b.item_id
  return items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.keyname - a.keyname;
  });
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
return items.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[keyname] - a[keyname];
});
```

When you do `a.keyname` you're actually looking for the property `keyname` in `a` itself.